# Rails: How can i set empty array with current parameters

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms, parameters

my application want to send empty array if check_box_tag is unchecked

This is my hidden_field_tag code

```
<%= hidden_field_tag('user[roles][]') %>
```

now i get parameter

```
"user"=>{"roles"=>[""]}
```

i want to instead with

```
 "user"=>{"roles"=>[]}
```

please guides

Comment: I would try with `<%= hidden_field_tag('user[roles][]', value: nil) %>`

Comment: juanpastas it doesn't work, it show "user"=>{"roles"=>["{:value=>nil}"] to me T_T

Comment: sorry `<%= hidden_field_tag('user[roles][]', nil) %>`

Comment: juanpastas, still not work sir, it show "user"=>{"roles"=>[""]} but i want  "user"=>{"roles"=>[]}" T_T

Comment: Ok, now i can fixed it , i forgot about parameters must send with string always (It's my bad)
and i can use controller to translates [""] to []

Comment: yes, but seems is not a way to send it empty from client...

Comment: exactly  juanpastas, let me know if you have a best way, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant prevent rails from assigning "" as default value but you can remove empty strings from an array in the controller like this:

```
@arr = params["user"]["roles"].map{ |x|
  x unless x.empty?
  nil if x.empty?
}.compact
```

The `map` replaces empty strings with `nil` and `compact` removes the nil values from the array.

Comment: it' seem ok, but now i used `params.map{ |key, val| val.delete_if {|elem| elem.empty? } if val.is_a? (Array)}` do you have any idea?

Comment: How about `params["user"]["roles"].delete_if { |r| r.blank? }`

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= hidden_field_tag('user[roles][]', nil) %>
```